# Neighbor of non measurable function still non measurable

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, measurable-functions

Does there exists a non-measurable function $f : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that for every function $g : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ with $$ |g(x)-f(x)|<1 $$
for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$, then $g$ is also non-measurable?

I am thinking about function $f$ such that $f(x)=|x|+100$ for $x$ in any non-measurable subset of $\mathbb{R}$ and $f(x)=|x|-100$ for $x$ in any measurable set of $\mathbb{R}$. But I don't know whether this works or not since measurable set and non-measurable can intersect. Thanks.

Note : the measure here is Lebesgue measure

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your basic idea works. Fix a non-measurable subset $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ and define $f = 3 1_A$. If $g$ is measurable then $g^{-1}(2, \infty)$ is measurable. If $|f(x) - g(x)| < 1$ for every $x$ then $g(x) > 2$ iff $x \in A$ so that $A$ is measurable which is a contradiction.

Comment: Thank you, I was in doubt whether there exists a nonempty intersection of a non-measurable set and a measurable one so I didn't try characteristic function.